# Select all 5 poles

Tags: selection-tools, topology

I'm cleaning up geometry of a house's foundations (incl. walls, stairs, floors, roof etc). It's all one piece.

I need to select all 5 poles. I can't use select similar in this case, because I have no idea where and if there are 5 poles. I tried all the tools in the select menu, but selecting 5 poles doesn't seem to be there.

I can select and count 6+ poles, using the MeshLint addon. But not 5 poles.

Is there a script available that selects 5 poles or any-poles?

I would also like to ask, is it a big problem if I let slip several 6 poles? As I said, I have the house walls all in one piece, including the 2 staircases. And I don't seem to be able to avoid these few 6 poles. They are connecting the stairs to the wall. There are 8 of them. Is it a big problem?

Or is it better to split the stairs from the walls, so they don't connect with 6 poles?

[image: Example of 6-poles]

Comment: *"I can't use select similar in this case, because I have no idea where and if there are 5 poles"* not really clear if there actually are 5 poles but if you find one you can select central vertex and run Shift+G > Amount of Connected Edges. That said I don't think there's any reason to connect stairs to walls, it will be much easier to handle with mesh if those are separate

Comment: This has everything to do with what are you cleaning the mesh FOR. Do you want to make a rendering or export it for real-time use? Are proper UVs important and what about material slots? You can select 5(+) poles by selecting 4-pole and using Shift-G Select Similar and from options select > operator but working like that won't necessarily help you towards better topology.

Comment: I tried the Shift-G with Amount of Connected Edges trick (either with or without the > operator) and it works.